# What is the difference between the two codes in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

I was trying the problem Hash Tables: Ice Cream Parlor on Hackerrank. It is a simple question, but here is the bizzare situation i got to. How does the change of data structure matter?
Case 1:

```
void whatFlavors(vector<int> cost, int money) {
    int ans1,ans2;
    vector<int> arr(100,0);          //notice this
    for(int i=0;i<cost.size();i++){
        if(arr[money-cost[i]]!=0){
            ans1=i+1;ans2=arr[abs(money-cost[i])];
            if(ans1>ans2){
                cout<<ans2<<" "<<ans1<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<ans2<<" "<<ans1<<endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
            arr[cost[i]]=i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

And output is:
[image]

Case 2:
code:

```
void whatFlavors(vector<int> cost, int money) {
    int arr[100]={0}; //notice this
    int ans1,ans2;
    for(int i=0;i<cost.size();i++){
        if(arr[money-cost[i]]!=0){
            ans1=i+1;ans2=arr[abs(money-cost[i])];
            if(ans1>ans2){
                cout<<ans2<<" "<<ans1<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<ans2<<" "<<ans1<<endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
            arr[cost[i]]=i+1;
        }
    }

}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: The most likely answer is undefined behavior due to array overrun because of lack of bounds checking. Because this question fails to meet all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com [help], it's unlikely that a more complete answer will be possible. If you [edit] your question, remove all the eyesore images, and supplement it with a [mcve], then perhaps a better answer will be possible.

Comment: `int arr[100]={0};` is the same as `int arr[100]={};`. You are only assigning a 0 to the first element, then the others are default-initialized, which by luck is also 0.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher`int arr[100]={0}` and `int arr[100]={}` are both required to initialize the full array with zeros. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: But not in the same way: If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are value-initialized.

Comment: There is no term "value-initialized" in the C standard. It is unclear what you mean by it. The standard says the remaining elements are initialised in the same way static storage duration objects are, which is to say, to zero. All ways to initialise something to zero have the same effect, namely, initialising that something to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just notice this part of your code:

```
if(arr[money-cost[i]]!=0){
    ans1=i+1;ans2=arr[abs(money-cost[i])];
```

This means that your expect `money-cost[i]` to be negative for some values of `i`. So you end up reading locations that are outside your array (vector or array) which will lead to undefined behavior **in both cases**.